# Devops custom rule to increment a field

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

In DevOps, I need a field which can be a counter and get incremented +1 whenever the work item state change from "Done" to "In progress". I tried to have an integer field and set the Rule as mentioned below 
**condition: when a work item state changes From "Done" to "In Progress"** 
**Action: Set the value of "Field" to "+1".**

[image]

This rule is changing the value of the counter from 0 to 1 for the very first time only. However the counter does not keep incrementing whenever I change the work Item state from "Done" to "In progress"

Please suggest me an approach to do it.

Comment: Your rule is not an increment at all, you're just assigning value "+1", aka. the positive number 1.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to increment the value with the help of rule.

Comment: Did you read the answer that's been posted? You haven't at least commented it in any way

Comment: @adyasha You can't achieve what you want using the rules. You need to check Shamrai Aleksander's answer, he has given the workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar use case: counting the amount of times a work item fails testing (gets moved back from Resolved to Active). Since I don't need a true increment, just want an indication whether this has happened once, twice, thrice or more, I made a couple of rules, one for each increment, like this:

[image: Rule to increment counter from 1 to 2]

It won't help in any increment scenario, but possibly it helps some people.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Devops does not support increments. You can try to use:

1. [TFS Aggregator (Web Service)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-web-service).
2. Create rules with [Azure Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/). It contains triggers and [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/) to update work items.
3. Create a [custom application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops). Add field like "Need Increment" with default value "false". Create Rule - condition: when a work item state changes From "Done" to "In Progress" Action: Set the value of "Need Increment" to "true". Your custom application updates you increment field and set "Need Increment" to "false".

Comment: Thank you so very much, Alex.Appriciated your help. I was trying to do this with the help of the Azure Logic App. But still facing some issue while setting up the property of a field

Comment: @adyasha pls create a new question and we will discuss it.